# Split 2D numpy array with condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I want to split a 2D array based on the value in row 13.
Input is a 2D Numpy array, but I cant figure out how to create Arrays as an output, as np.append gives me tupels.
(So I can for example not use np.median on it)

```
import numpy as np

D = np.load('train_data.npy')

E = []
F = []

for i, item in enumerate(D):
    if D[i][13]==0:
        np.append(E,item)
    else:
        np.append(F,item)

threshold=np.median(E[:, 7])
#Throws error, because E is a now tuple. It works on D.
```

Comment: `np.append` is nothing like the list append method.  Don't try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorized version of the code above.

```
import numpy as np
E = D[np.isclose(D[:,13], 0)].ravel().tolist()
F = D[~np.isclose(D[:,13], 0)].ravel().tolist()
```

It is better to use almost equal comparison when working with floating point numbers, because in some cases (due to errors of number representation in memory), e.g. 1.0e-20 may be treated non-equal to zero.

Comment: This still has a tuple as output. How can I get it to create a 2D array again ?

Comment: Just don't apply `.ravel` and `.tolist`, leave only:  D[np.isclose(D[:,13], 0)]